# Error Handling in Nested try-except in python

Tags: python, error-handling, nested, try-except

The piece of code i have looks like this:

```
try:
    funcProneToError()
    #codeBlock1
except:
    #errorMessage

def funcProneToError():
    try:
       #raise error
    except:
       #erorMessage
```

Now the problem is that if an error is raised in funcProneToError(), the code skips codeBlock1 and prints error message twice.
is there any way to bypass this?
iwant to be able to run codeblock1 even if an error is detected in the function.

Also im coming here after a really long time so ignore any formatting mishaps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If `funcPronedToError` catches errors and doesn't throw, why reach outer `except` block?

Comment: You are catching the exception in `funcProneToError`, so `#codeBlock1` should run and only one error will be printed. Please edit the question with runnable code that demonstrates the behavior you are trying to change.

Comment: drop the except block if you dont wanna print the error

Comment: *"iwant to be able to run codeblock1 even if an error is detected"* - it looks like you are looking for the `finally` block in python.

Comment: also - I know this is pseudocode - but never ever use except without an error type. If you really want to rip all the guardrails off, you can use `except Exception:`, which will catch all types of exceptions except SystemExit or KeyboardInterrupt. But it's best to catch specific exception types so you still get a (useful) error message if things go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    funcProneToError()
except:
    #errorMessage
finally:
    #codeBlock1

def funcProneToError():
    try:
       #raise error
```

(1) Your code handles the exception twice therefore the error message is printed twice.

Remove the except block in funcProneToError(). funcProneToError() raises an exception and this exception is handled (only once) after the function has been called.

(2) Use a 'finally' block so that codeBlock1 prints regardless of whether there was an exception raised.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: did you mean to remove the `try:` in `funcProneToError`? as it is, your answer is invalid syntax

Comment: Hey, thanks for the message, worked like a charm.
I wish i could catch the error in the function itself but i guess i wont have that luxury.